# Can I parse a string from a filename to help find the file in its subfolders with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, parsing

I am looking for a series of files that follow a very rigid filename format, but are in different numbered subfolders based on a string in the filename.

1. The filename is always "LAX_CA_Baseball_<8 digits>.pdf
2. The files are always 4 folders deep, and the top two folders are always \\fileserver\sports\pdf
3. The last 4 digits always represent the bottom two subfolders, for example LAX_CA_Baseball_12345678.pdf would be located in "\\fileserver\sports\pdf\56\78"
4. There are tens of millions of files in total, so just searching for the filename from \\fileserver\sports\pdf will take a very long time

Can I write something in powershell that will parse the last 4 digits of the filename, convert that to the bottom subfolders, and then get the file and copy it to a new folder?

Comment: "Can I" is the wrong question when it comes to programming. 99% of the time the answer is yes, it just depends on how much time and effort you're willing to put into research and testing. Please put in some effort trying to do it yourself and come back with any more specific technical questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have the filename somewhere, you can extract the digits and construct the path with a regular expression:

```
$f = "LAX_CA_Baseball_12345678.pdf"

if ($f -match ".*_\d{4,4}(\d\d)(\d\d)\.pdf") {
  $sourcePath = "\\server\sports\pdf\$($matches[1])\$($matches[2])\$f"
  $destinationPath = "some other folder path"
  Copy-Item $sourcePath $destinationPath 
} else {
  Write-Error "Can't determine folder from filename $f"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is not only correct, but also gave me the structure to research things outside my range of knowledge like regex and arrays. I do have the original filenames and the next step will be to pull "$f" from a file with a list of the filenames, but that I'll try to figure out on my own.